# Develop iPad Version or iPhone Version first?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitview, ios-universal-app

I have just finished developing an iPhone app and now I wish to make it a Universal App.  I'm having issues incorporating a UISplitView into my current code to accommodate multiple detail views.  I have looked at Apple's MultipleDetailViews sample code and have tried to insert into my project but it's becoming more of a headache than it should.

I'll copy all the project files from Apple's MultipleDetailViews sample code into my project, adjust my app delegate to check to see if an iPad's running, set the window to add a subView of splitViewController.view, but all I get is blank white screen when I build and run.

So my question is, do I develop the iPad version from a new project and then add my iPhone project files when I'm done?

OR

Do I make a separate iPad app and forget the whole Universal App?

Thoughts and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly the answer to your question, but why don't you write a simple 'toy' universal app that does something really trivial, e.g. press a button, show the current time. Then, once you've done it, you might have an easier time converting the real app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is more to creating a Universal build from the outset than just checking for iPad view.

You need to set the project up as a universal build in the build settings. I know default projects that are universal create a group of folders with a main view for iPhone and iPad. You will need to create separate views for iPhone and iPad.

I would create a dummy project that is universal and compare settings and default values. Try adding these to your project and see if you have better results.

But I wouldn't think you should put one before the other. Build the one you think you will have the most success with first, then if you still need it, build out for the other. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've changed all the build settings to be a Universal app but am still haing no luck. As I mentioned, the iPhone app is done. Just thought maybe i was missing something trivial.

Answer (score 4):

I would start with a Universal Project and generate content for the iPad, I've found downsampling easier than upscaling :). Try and make everything generic (based off the view height and width). This will make conversion to the iPhone/iPod easier.